# Simulation of security against IP

Tags: honeypot, ip

I am pursuing a college project, in which I am running three fake services on three ports to protect the main service (say running at port 80). The concept is that if the user is malicious, he'll try to bring the services down and access the fake services. These ports adopt a blocking process of a connection request and record the IP and port of the client. These are logged and aren't granted access on service on port 80.So how do I test the system on my own laptop as I can send request from my own IP.

Comment: This question is very confusing. Please rephrase.

Comment: Your edit now makes the question clear. Rory's answer below is the answer you are looking for: VMs.

Comment: @schroeder,SO NOW QUESTION SHOULD BE REOPENED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you're looking to create some test machines to assess whether your IP address blocking system is working ok?

the usual way to do this would be to use another system and then give it the IP address you want to block.  Perhaps the most straightforward approach here is to use virtualization software (e.g. VMWare, Xen etc) to host the test machines.